# Returning Binary Search Tree Nodes in Zig Zag manner

Tags: java, binary-search

I tried to implement an answer for the algorithm question given below. I implemented two different solutions. I couldn't decide which one is better. ( Maybe none )

Note: Node class and ZigZag interface are given along with the question.

**Problem Definition** A binary tree is given. Return a list of nodes in Zig Zag manner. state the Big-O runtime and space complexity of your implementation.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Stack;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.Collections;

/**
 * Print a binary tree in zig zag way... that is:
 * ......a.........
 * ....b....c.......
 * ..d...e...f...g..
 * .h.i.j.k.l.m.n.o.
 * 
 * should be printed as a-c-b-d-e-f-g-o-n-m-l-k-j-i-h
 * 
 * what data structure will u use for that?
 * 
 */
public class BinaryZigZagTraversal {

/* ------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* DATA DEFINITION(S) */
/* ------------------------------------------------------------- */

/**
 * ZigZag interface instance
 */
private ZigZag zigZagInstance;

/**
 * Tree node
 * 
 */
public class Node {

    private int value;
    private Node left;
    private Node right;

    public Node(int value, Node left, Node right) {
        this.value = value;
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }

    public Node getLeft() {
        return this.left;
    }

    public Node getRight() {
        return this.right;
    }

    protected void setLeft(Node leftNode) {
        this.left = leftNode;
    }

    protected void setRight(Node rightNode) {
        this.right = rightNode;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.valueOf( getValue() );
    }
}

/**
 * ZigZag interface
 * 
 */
public interface ZigZag {
    public List<Node> GetZigZagOrder(Node rootNode);
}

/* ------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* SOLUTION- 1 */
/* ------------------------------------------------------------- */

/**
 * My BFS-like Implementation
 * 
 * @author ozkansari
 *
 * Total Time complexity: O(2n) -> n+n+(n/8)
 * Total Space complexity: O(3n) -> size(bfsQueue) + size(resultList) + size(levelNodes) 
 */
public class ZigZagBFSImpl implements ZigZag {

    @Override
    public List<Node> GetZigZagOrder(Node rootNode) {
        Queue<Node> bfsQueue = new LinkedList<Node>();

        List<Node> resultList = new ArrayList<Node>();
        bfsQueue.add(rootNode);

        int currentLevel = 1;
        while(!bfsQueue.isEmpty()) {

            // O(n)
            // Remove all first
            List<Node> levelNodes = new ArrayList<Node>();
            while(!bfsQueue.isEmpty()) {
                Node n = bfsQueue.remove();
                levelNodes.add(n);
            }

            // O(n)
            boolean hasChildNode = false;
            for (Node currentNode : levelNodes) {
                Node firstNode = currentNode.getLeft();
                Node secondNode = currentNode.getRight();

                if(firstNode!=null) {
                    bfsQueue.add( firstNode );
                    hasChildNode=true;
                }

                if(secondNode!=null) {
                    bfsQueue.add( secondNode );
                    hasChildNode=true;
                }

            }

            // O(n/8)
            if(currentLevel%2==0) {
                Collections.reverse(levelNodes);
            }
            resultList.addAll(levelNodes);

            if(hasChildNode) {
                currentLevel++;
            }

        }

        return resultList;
    }
}

/* ------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* SOLUTION- 2 */
/* ------------------------------------------------------------- */

/**
 * My ZigZag Implementation
 * 
 * @author ozkansari
 *
 * Total Time complexity: O(n) -> n+n
 * Total Space complexity: O(n) -> size(levels)
 */
public class ZigZagStackImpl implements ZigZag {

    /**
     * Map of stacks to represent tree levels
     */
    Map<Integer,Stack<Node>> levels=new HashMap<Integer,Stack<Node>>();

    @Override
    public List<Node> GetZigZagOrder(Node rootNode) {

        // Initialize next level
        initLevels(rootNode, 1);

        // Find result list
        List<Node> resultList = new ArrayList<Node>();

        for (int i=1; ; i++) {

            Stack<Node> levelStack = levels.get(i);
            if(levelStack==null) break;

            while(!levelStack.empty()) {
                Node currentNode = null;

                if(i%2==0) { // right side
                    currentNode = levelStack.pop();
                } else {
                    currentNode = levelStack.firstElement();
                    levelStack.remove(currentNode);
                }

                resultList.add(currentNode);
            }

        }

        return resultList;
    }

    /**
     * Helper recursive method
     *
     * @param currentNode
     * @param currentLevel
     */
    private void initLevels(Node currentNode, Integer levelIndex) {

        if(levelIndex<=0) {
            levelIndex=1;
        }

        // Initialize first root level if required
        if(levelIndex==1){
            Stack<Node> rootLevel = new Stack<Node>();
            rootLevel.add(currentNode);
            levels.put(1,rootLevel);
            levelIndex=2;
        }

        Node leftNode = currentNode.getLeft();
        Node rightNode = currentNode.getRight();

        if(leftNode==null && rightNode==null) {
            return;
        } 

        Stack<Node> currentLevel = levels.get(levelIndex);
        if(currentLevel==null) {
            currentLevel = new Stack<Node>();
            levels.put(levelIndex,currentLevel);
        }

        if(leftNode!=null) {
            currentLevel.push(leftNode);
            if(leftNode.getLeft()!=null || leftNode.getRight()!=null) {
                initLevels(leftNode,levelIndex+1);
            } 
        }

        if(rightNode!=null) {
            currentLevel.push(rightNode);
            if(rightNode.getLeft()!=null || rightNode.getRight()!=null) {
                initLevels(rightNode,levelIndex+1);
            }
        }

    }

}

/**
 * 
 * @return ZigZag instance
 */
public ZigZag getZigZagInstance(){
    if(zigZagInstance==null) {
        zigZagInstance = new ZigZagBFSImpl();
    }
    return zigZagInstance;
}


/* ------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* TEST METHOD(S) */
/* ------------------------------------------------------------- */

/**
 * Main method to test the ZigZag coding sample. 
 * I actually prefer to test my code using JUnit but the result is requested to be in one file.
 * 
 * @author ozkansari
 * 
 */
public String test(int nodeCount) {

    ZigZag zigZagImpl = getZigZagInstance();
    List<Node> zigZagOrderedList = zigZagImpl.GetZigZagOrder(generateDummyBinaryTree(nodeCount));

    StringBuffer sbf = new StringBuffer();
    for (Node node : zigZagOrderedList) {
        sbf.append(node + " ");
    }
    System.out.println(sbf.toString());
    return sbf.toString();

}

/**
 * Generates a dummy binary tree and returns its root node
 * 
 */
private Node generateDummyBinaryTree(int nodeCount){
    List<Node> sampleData = new ArrayList<Node>();
    for(int i=1;i<=nodeCount;i++) {
        Node currentNode = new Node(i,null,null);;
        sampleData.add(currentNode);
    }
    int j=1;

    for (Node node : sampleData) {
        int index = j*2;

        Node rightNode = index+1<=sampleData.size() ? sampleData.get(index) : null;
        Node leftNode = index<=sampleData.size() ? sampleData.get(index-1) : null;

        node.setRight(rightNode);
        node.setLeft(leftNode);

        j++;
    }

    return sampleData.get(0);
}

/**
 * Main method to test my sample code.
 * 
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BinaryZigZagTraversal z = new BinaryZigZagTraversal ();
    System.out.println( z.test(1).equals("1 ") );
    System.out.println( z.test(2).equals("1 2 ") );
    System.out.println( z.test(4).equals("1 3 2 4 ") );
    System.out.println( z.test(12).equals("1 3 2 4 5 6 7 12 11 10 9 8 ") );
    System.out.println( z.test(16).equals("1 3 2 4 5 6 7 15 14 13 12 11 10 9 8 16 ") );
    System.out.println( z.test(24).equals("1 3 2 4 5 6 7 15 14 13 12 11 10 9 8 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 ") );
}
```

}

Comment: Time and Space complexity is never stated as  O(3n) or  O(2n).

O(a*n + b) = O(n).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First of all you are not really using Queue and Stack in any specific way.
2. The following :

   ```
   currentNode = levelStack.firstElement();
   levelStack.remove(currentNode);
   ```

   can be more concisely expressed as:

   ```
   currentNode = levelStack.remove(0);
   ```
3. In any case removing the first element of a `Stack` is slow.
4. If you are going to remove elements from both ends of a list (as is the case with `levelStack`) you should use a `Deque`. LinkedList implements Deque.
5. The following :

   ```
   List<Node> levelNodes = new ArrayList<Node>();
   while(!bfsQueue.isEmpty()) {
       Node n = bfsQueue.remove();
       levelNodes.add(n);
   }
   ```

   can be more concisely expressed as:

   ```
   List<Node> levelNodes = new ArrayList<Node>(bfsQueue);
   ```
6. ZigZagBFSImpl is O(n), but ZigZagStackImpl is > O(n) (due to stack.remove(first-element) being O(stack-size))
7. Generally avoid `StringBuffer` in favor of `StringBuilder` , because of synchronization overhead.
8. Throw `IllegalArgumentException` for illegal arguments instead of continuing execution with unexpected behaviour :

   ```
   if(levelIndex<=0) {
       levelIndex=1;
   }
   ```
9. `Integer levelIndex` should be `int levelIndex` since passing in `null` causes an exception, and therefore not a valid argument.